# Conditional confirmation dialog for fileupload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have fileuploader component[image: fileuploader compoenent]

with xhtml code

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{MyClass.handleFileUpload}" />
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
</h:form>
```

and backing method

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){
if(check())
   if(*ConfirmDialogReturnTrue*)
   //doSomethingWithUploadFileMethod()
else
//doSomethingWithUploadFileMethod()
}
```

and I want to make conditional dialog like this

[image]

check method is doing with another parameter before return true or false 
if check return true , it will make confirmation dialog and if user press confirm , it will do the same as when check() return false

I need some help with this dialog

and another question ,  how can I make modal dialog when user click on calendar icon

[image]

I'm not used to xhtml or JavaScript side so this is kinda hard for me

thanks for help

Comment: My guess is that the logic in `check` should be implemented in JavaScript?

Comment: Please one question per question.

Comment: Just open a new client side dialog via a request context and process the submission of that new dialog in a new server side method